# determine source (ie: JavaScript code, server code, browser cache, etc..) of how HTML input field gets its value

Tags: javascript, html, input, firebug, mozilla

Is it possible to put a breakpoint on an HTML input box (say using Firebug or some other plug-in) and determine what is actually setting the value in the input field?  **OR** determine the (last) source of the value--meaning what set the value last?  I know how to set breakpoints into the JavaScript using Firebug, but not the other way around.  I am pretty certain the value of the input box is happening client side because it's only happening in Mozilla Firefox (and I think it's proven in the link below from my previous question).  I don't know if there's any other way an input field can get populated on the client side other than with JavaScript.  If you know of a way please comment and I'll up vote you.

See this question for more details:
[ASP.NET TextBox (HTML input field) populates with username automatically when form loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900326/asp-net-textbox-pulls-in-data-when-form-loads)

If you can tell me the answer to this question, I'll let you get credit for both questions (this and the link above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Firefox/Firebug.  The best you can do is get JS to (usually) notify you or log changes as they happen.

Chrome is slightly better, because it lets you set global, Event Listener breakpoints.  So if you set breakpoints on keyboard, mouse, and control events, then Chrome will step into the appropriate JS code (if any) that fires on those events. (And one of those *usually* fires when an input changes.)

In most browsers, but especially Firefox, an input can get a value in one of these ways:

1. User action.
2. Javascript.
3. A browser extension/add-on or plugin.
4. The browser will fill in the last user values in many cases, unless instructed not to. See ["Three Aspects of Autocompletion"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/how_to_turn_off_form_autocompletion#Three_Aspects_of_Autocompletion).
5. Predefined values, coded into the HTML.

---

You can get a better idea about what JS might be doing during page load by using [Firebug's profiler](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/10/firebug-tutorial-logging-profiling-and-commandline-part-ii).

Add code like this to the top of the page's `<HEAD>` section. :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.profile("Startup JS Profiler");
    window.addEventListener ("load", function() {
            console.profileEnd("Startup JS Profiler"); 
        }, 
        false 
    );
</script>
```

Then watch the console while the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind an `onChange` handler to the `INPUT` element and then log information to the console. `console.trace` would also be helpful here (if you're using Firebug).

Answer (score 0):

Until someone answers this question, there are no tools for Firefox to determine the source.  But I did figure out that the browser does set data on it's own.  The remember password functionality in Mozilla sets text in a TextBox/input field on its own.  See details in the hyperlink within my question.